# RowNumberer doesn't show numbers over 99 in Google Chrome

Tags: extjs

I'm having trouble with Ext.grid.RowNumberer in Google Chrome. When the store of the GridPanel I'm using it with has more than 99 records in it, the RowNumberer shows only dots for them instead of the correct numbers. In Firefox everything works fine.

So, is it a common Ext Js bug or am I doing something wrong?

The version of Ext Js is 3.3.0

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually the dots appear when the cell content does not fit in its width. Try to increase RowNumberer's width.

```
columns: [
    new Ext.grid.RowNumberer({width: 50}),
    // other columns
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in ExtJS version 4.1.

Setting constant width may also not work for me as the number of rows can range from 10 to some thousands in my case. So the fix is to make the row numberer column resizable. It can be achieved with the following line of code

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer',{resizable: true})
```

Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

The column width is too small to display the row number. You have to increase the width:

```
RowNumberer rn = new RowNumberer();
rn.setResizable(true);
rn.setWidth(65);
```